# Why does the SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Setup fail with a missing izqm71js.chm?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to install a SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition in a VM running Windows Server 2003 alongside a running SQL Server 2000 instance. But the setup always fails complaining that the file `izqm71js.chm` is missing or inaccessible. And indeed, it is missing.

What am I doing wrong? As far as I have read there should be no problem setting up both SQL Servers on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your installation media is corrupted. Are you using a DVD, an .ISO file mounted via virtual DVD software or from a folder containing the setup.exe and the additional files?

Comment: I'm installing from a folder. The files were downloaded from MSDNAA.

Comment: I assume you have downloaded an .ISO file from MSDN?

Comment: No, I downloaded it throught Microsofts Dreamspark portal (formerly MSDN Acadamic Alliance) and it was not an ISO, or MS's downloader extracted the iso to a folder but do not think so.

Comment: Can you download the installer as an .ISO? If not, I have one suggestion: download a trial version of SQL Server in .ISO format and get the missing file from that .ISO.